# Add text only to lines that don't begin with "blah"

Tags: notepad++, regex

I want to add data to the end of only certain lines in Notepad++. I only want to add a number to the lines that *do not* begin with **"SRH"**.

> **SRH MAIN LABORATORY 1230300025|1230300004|1412300001**
>
> **SRH MAIN LABORATORY 1230300004|1230300025|1412300001**
>
> LABCORP LAB   1230300004|1230300000
>
> QUEST
>   LAB   1230300004|1231200002|1230300000|1231200003|1231200201|1231200202
>
> LABCORP LAB   1230300004|1230300000
>
> QUEST LAB 1230300004|1230300000|1231200201|1231200202
>
> **SRH QUEST   1230300004|1230300000|1231200201|1231200202**

Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is using a negative lookahead:

```
(?!SRH).*
```

This ensures that every line caught in the regex will NOT begin with "SRH".